# MS word has wrong format for page number and hyperlinks after installing EndNote x20

Tags: microsoft-word, endnote

I am using win 10, ms-word and recently installed EndNote x20. After installation of EndNote, any existing word document faces the following problems:

- A hyperlink in the text, for example [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), now shows with curly brackets around at, for example, {HYPERLINK "www.google.com"}
- A page number in the footer previously showing as 1,2, etc., now shows as {PAGE  * Arabic  * MERGEFORMAT}

Please help me resolve this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Since this issue affects all existing Word files, please check if this issue persists after uninstalling EndNote?
In addition, I also recommend that you try to [open the word files in safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-windows-pc-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72) for a check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see are field codes. Press Alt+F9 to toggle them off (or on).

See [List of field codes in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/list-of-field-codes-in-word-1ad6d91a-55a7-4a8d-b535-cf7888659a51).

Comment: Here is my table of keyboard shortcuts dealing with fields. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Function You may have to add the Fn key to the key combination.  If on a Mac, the shortcut is Opt+F9 or Fn+Opt+F9.